# How can I access database inside zend framework 2 plugin

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

## I need to access database inside zend framework2 plugin. I have to create ACL using database and for this purpose I need to access database inside plugin.

Here is my module.config.php

```
return array(
        // added for Acl   ###################################
        'controller_plugins' => array(
            'invokables' => array(
               'MyAclPlugin' => 'MyAcl\Controller\Plugin\MyAclPlugin',
             )
         ),
        // end: added for Acl   ###################################    
);
```

Here is my module.php

```
namespace MyAcl;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager; // added for module specific layouts. ericp
// added for Acl  ###################################
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent,
    Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

// end: added for Acl   ###################################
//class Module
class Module {

    public function getConfig() {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    // added for Acl   ###################################
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach('route', array($this, 'loadConfiguration'), 2);
        //you can attach other function need here...
    }

    public function loadConfiguration(MvcEvent $e) {
        $application = $e->getApplication();
        $sm = $application->getServiceManager();
        $sharedManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        $router = $sm->get('router');
        $request = $sm->get('request');

        $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
        if (null !== $matchedRoute) {
            $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) use ($sm) {
                $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('MyAclPlugin')
                        ->doAuthorization($e); //pass to the plugin...    
            }, 2
            );
        }
    }

    // end: added for Acl   ###################################

    /*
     *  // added init() func for module specific layouts. ericp
     * http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2
     */
    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager) {
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
            // This event will only be fired when an ActionController under the MyModule namespace is dispatched.
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            //$controller->layout('layout/zfcommons'); // points to module/Album/view/layout/album.phtml
        }, 100);
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

}
```

And my plugin MyAclPlugin.php

## I need to access some table (role, resource) from plugin, so that I can configure this resource allocation using a UI. Is there anyway I can access database from plugin. Please let me know the process.

```
namespace MyAcl\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin,
    Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer,
    Zend\Permissions\Acl\Acl,
    Zend\Permissions\Acl\Role\GenericRole as Role,
    Zend\Permissions\Acl\Resource\GenericResource as Resource;

use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use DataSource\Model\AgentModel;
use DataSource\Model\OfficeModel;
use DataSource\Model\UserModel;

class MyAclPlugin extends AbstractPlugin{
    
    protected $constants;
    protected $userModel;
    protected $agentModel;
    protected $user;


    protected $sesscontainer;

    private function getSessContainer() {
        if (!$this->sesscontainer) {
            $this->sesscontainer = new SessionContainer('zftutorial');
        }
        return $this->sesscontainer;
    }

    public function doAuthorization($e) {
        
        $acl = new Acl();
        $acl->deny();
        
        //$this->createService();
        
        ############################# ROLES ####################################
        $acl->addRole(new Role('anonymous'));
        $acl->addRole(new Role('crm'), 'anonymous');
        $acl->addRole(new Role('agent'), 'crm');
        $acl->addRole(new Role('admin'), 'agent');
        $acl->addRole(new Role('superAdmin'), 'admin');
        ############################ End ROLES #################################
                
        ###########################  RESOURCES #################################
        
        //------------------------- Front End Resources ------------------------
        
        $acl->addResource('application');
        
        //------------------------- Admin Template Resources -------------------
        $acl->addResource('admin');
        
        $acl->addResource('ta-authentication');
        $acl->addResource('ta-home'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-lead'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-listing'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-website'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-craigslist'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-configuration'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-single-property-website'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-open-house-schedule'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-social-media'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-office'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-agent'); 
        $acl->addResource('ta-blog'); 
                
        //------------------------- Rest API Resources -------------------------
        //
        // everything sould be protected except login
        //only anonymous user privileges
        
        //only crm user privileges + anonymous user privileges
        $acl->addResource('admin-rest-lead'); 
        $acl->addResource('admin-rest-lead-event'); 
        $acl->addResource('admin-rest-lead-task'); 
        $acl->addResource('admin-rest-lead-document');
        $acl->addResource('admin-rest-lead-group');
        $acl->addResource('admin-rest-notification'); 
                
        ########################### Resources ##################################
        
        ########################### Intagent PERMISSIONS #######################
        // $acl->allow('role', 'resource', 'controller:action');
        
        //--------------------frontend permission-------------------------------
        //--------------------template permission-------------------------------
        
        $acl->allow('anonymous', 'application');
        $acl->allow('anonymous', 'admin', 'index:index');
        $acl->allow('anonymous', 'admin', 'authentication:login');
        
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:index');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:form');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:group');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:event');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:task');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:task-category');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'lead:document');
        
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'configuration:help');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin', 'configuration:notification');
        //---------------------admin resources permission-----------------------
        
        //only crm user privileges + anonymous user privileges
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin-rest-lead'); 
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin-rest-lead-event'); 
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin-rest-lead-task'); 
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin-rest-lead-document');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin-rest-lead-group');
        $acl->allow('crm', 'admin-rest-notification'); 
        
        //only agent user privileges        
        $acl->allow('agent', 'admin-rest-authentication');
        $acl->allow('agent', 'admin-rest-help'); 
        $acl->allow('agent', 'admin-rest-utility');
        $acl->allow('agent', 'admin-rest-blog');
        
        //only admin user privileges 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-configuration'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-configuration-email'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-configuration-general'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-configuration-social-media'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-configuration-user'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-website'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-template'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-email-type'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-listing');
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-user'); 
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-single-property-website');
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-open-house-schedule');
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-office');
        $acl->allow('admin', 'admin-rest-agent');
        
        //only super admin privileges
        $acl->allow('superAdmin', 'admin-rest-country');
        $acl->allow('superAdmin', 'admin-rest-state');
        $acl->allow('superAdmin', 'admin-rest-currency'); 
        $acl->allow('superAdmin', 'admin-rest-timezone'); 
        $acl->allow('superAdmin', 'admin-rest-role'); 
        $acl->allow('superAdmin', 'admin-rest-resource');
        
        ####################### End Intagent PERMISSIONS #######################
        
        
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleName = strtolower(substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\')));
        $role = (!$this->getSessContainer()->role ) ? 'anonymous' : $this->getSessContainer()->role;
        //echo $this->user->getId();
        //$role = (!$this->user->getRole() && !$this->user->getRole()->getName()) ? 'crm' : $this->user->getRole()->getName();
        $role = "crm";
        $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();

        $actionName = strtolower($routeMatch->getParam('action', 'not-found')); // get the action name  
        $controllerName = $routeMatch->getParam('controller', 'not-found'); // get the controller name
        $controllerName = explode('\\', $controllerName);
        $controllerName = strtolower(array_pop($controllerName));
        
        #################### Check Access ########################
        if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, $moduleName, $controllerName . ':' . $actionName)) {
            $router = $e->getRouter();
            
            //make a logout operation
            echo "Access Problem Role:{$role} is not allowed to Module:{$moduleName} Controller:{$controllerName} Action:{$actionName} " ;
            
            // $url    = $router->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'Login/auth')); // assemble a login route
//            $url = $router->assemble(array(), array('name' => 'authentication', 'action'=>'login'));
//            
//            $response = $e->getResponse();
//            $response->setStatusCode(302);
//            // redirect to login page or other page.
//            $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
//            
            $e->stopPropagation();
        }
    }


}
```

Please let me know how can I do that.

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

In your "MyAclPlugin" create a method like:

```
public function setServiceLocator($sl)
{
    $this->sl = $sl;
}
```

Then in your MyAcl module.php create a method:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myAclPlugin' => function($sm)
    {
        $plugin = new Controller\Plugin\MyAclPlugin();
        $plugin->setServicelocator($sm);
        return $plugin;
    },
        ),
    );
}
```

Then in your MyAclPlugin you could probably do something like:

```
$dbAdapter = $this->sl->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did exactly what you said but it is not working. I also check that setServiceLocator funtion is never executed.  Is there anything you are missing. My main purpose is to get the service location from plugin and if I can get that service location on plugin then I can call any DB class which I want.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the previous answer from Peter you could implement the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` in your Plugin, so you can use `$this->getServiceocator()` in it.

This method should return a class like `ControllerPluginManager`. From this you must be able to call `getService(Manager|Locator)` (i'm not sure right now) to get the top-level ServiceManager that knows everything about all ServiceManagers. There you should be able to call `get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')`.

**But** some ZF2 maintainer are sure that this technique is bad practise ([see Github issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5168))